# Accessing and changing variables from a struct in a struct with pointers

Tags: c, struct

Tearing my hair out on this one.

So I have 2 structs:

```
struct character_data{
    (a billion other varibles);
    struct skill_stuff *skillstats;
};

struct skill_stuff{
    int skill;
    int skillname;
};
```

My problem is, I'm trying to access data in `*skillstats`, but I crash every time.

```
void this_skill(character_data ch){
    int skill = 1;
    ch->skillstats->skill = skill;
}
```

Even trying to just access it in a print function, using ("%d", ch->skillstats->skill) crashes it. I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: Could you please specify the language you use

Comment: your creating skillstats object or not ?

Comment: How are you allocating memory for all those structs? Note that you are passing the struct `ch` by *value* (at least in the posted snippet), not as a *pointer*. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].